# Laravel Relationship Getting All Children

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query which returns a table. I would like to also return a list of styles which relate to it from another table. I have tried many things but I can't find one which works. Any advice?

Query:

```
$data = YarnOrderLines::with('yarn_orders')
        ->with('yarns')->get(); //I would like to pull in YarnOrderLineStyles
```

YarnOrderLines:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'yarn_orders_id',
    'yarn_id',
    'qty',
    'price',
    'invoice_no',
    'qty_invoiced',
];
public function yarn_orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(YarnOrders::class);
}
public function yarns()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Yarn::class);
}

public function yarn_order_line_styles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(YarnOrderLineStyles::class)->with('yarn_orders')->with('yarns');
}
```

YarnOrderLineStyles (table with relating styles in I would like to pull in)

```
protected $fillable = [
    'yarn_order_lines_id',
    'order_id',
];
public function yarn_order_lines()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(YarnOrderLines::class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already getting 2 relations from YardOrderLines, so you just need to add another with statement. You can combine them all into 1 line like this:

```
 YarnOrderLines::with(['yarn_orders', 'yarns', 'yarn_order_line_styles'])
    ->get();
```

And remove the `with` statement on your relation inside of YarnOrderLines, so it really doesn't have a bearing on the Styles table.

Comment: I tried that but I get the error: "Call to undefined relationship [yarn_orders] on model [App\Models\YarnOrderLineStyles].". The relationship is between YarnOrderLines and YarnOrderLineStyles, not between YarnOrders and YarnOrderLineStyles?

Comment: Right, which is why you need to remove the with statements off of `return $this->hasMany(YarnOrderLineStyles::class)->with('yarn_orders')->with('yarns');`.